# How to evaluate performance and usability of a web application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, testing

I am developing a application server which takes a FASTA (Biology term, let it be a string) format `string` and process the request and provides some results. I have deployed it on `Tomcat web server`. 
Now , My question is I would like to know the load it can handle and I would like to pass inputs for some heavy requests and see the response time and availability of the server application.
How can I do this online or is there any other way to do?

My Application server is at [click here](http://protein.rnet.missouri.edu:8080/MongoTest/)

Comment: Check out JMeter or soap UI for load / performance testing... be mindful of questions such as 'how much load can in handle' greatly depend on the server you have (specs), how much bandwidth you have (assuming you have to share the network with others), how much latency you have with other systems (i.e. database layer, etc.) - so it typically is something hard to find out in just a couple of hours - it depends greatly on the environment so the fewer variables (such as time of the day, etc. ) you introduce from test to test, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @ochi about JMeter, this is good start for the performance test. Then if you looking the online tool I would recommend [Blazemeter](http://blazemeter.com/). This tool based on JMeter scripts but allows online test using Amazon EC2. Also it's provide good report extension.